# Should an interface function's return type only be an interface?

Tags: .net, class, interface

Should an interface method's return type only be an interface?

This might seem like a vague 'what's your opinion' question, but it's not, really!

Let's say I have 3 providers, all implementing my interface 'IDocProvider', and its function 'IGetDoc() as xxxx' - let's say purpose is for fetching Word docs from 3 different stores.

Now, should I make my return type class 'MyDocClass', or an interface?  I've been told Interfaces should only return Interface types.

A return type of interface such as IMyDoc seems the right thing to do, but it feels odd to have to have an implementation of IMyDoc when there will only ever be one implementation of that interface.  If return type is a class, then that class can't be in my model assembly, as thad cause a circular reference of course.

What's a workable approach, that saves me writing an implementation of IMyDoc?

Thanks, any answers appreciated!  p.s. using .NET 4.5

Comment: "I've been told Interfaces should only return Interface types." - by who? I've never heard that before, and there are plenty of counter-examples. It would be very odd for `IEnumerator<T>.MoveNext()` to have to return an interface around `bool` for example...

Comment: What circular reference do you mean? The return type should be in the same assembly as `IDocProvider`. I don't see a reason why you should return an interface.

Comment: No.  Needless abstraction is very detrimental to ever getting a project done.  You'll spend *months* abstracting the object model for a document and never write a line of executable code.  When it is finally done it still only ever knows how to handle a Word document.

Comment: But, if the return type is in the interface assembly then it (return type) can't refer to any other types in the model.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yeah let's assume I don't mean value types.